# How to set ComboBox selected item in ModelView?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, mvvm-light

I have static combo box items. My XAML look like this:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Model View:

```
    // How to set initial value here or in constructor?
    private ComboBoxItem _mySelectedItem;
    public ComboBoxItem MySelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _mySelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value = {0}", (value as ComboBoxItem).Name);
        }
    }
```

How can I set selected item of combo box having `Name`? I would like to set selected item in MV constructor, after reading from persistent storage.

Comment: You cann't do that. ComboBoxItem is a reference type and in your ViewModel you will not be able to get references of ComboBox items

Comment: otherwise, you can use SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem

Comment: SelectedIndex worked, but it's not the best solution. To make SelectedItem work I have to create and fill ComboBox items from ViewModel as I understand? If you know how, your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You must create it on ViewModel. I will put the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to add is the SelectedValuePath="Name" to your combo box. Then in your ViewModel constructor, add your startup Item like this. I made my SelectedDropDown property a string, not sure if you have to have it as a ComboBoxItem in your case.

```
 public MainFormViewModel()
    {
        SelectedDropDown = "cbi1";
    }
 private string _SelectedDropDown;
    public string SelectedDropDown
    {
        get { return _SelectedDropDown; }
        set { _SelectedDropDown = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDropDown"); }
    }
```

Here is the ComboBox Code, tested it and it works fine.

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,213,0,0" SelectedValuePath="Name"  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDropDown }"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create your collection from ViewModel in order to use SelectedItem

*.xaml (View)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Height="25"/>
```

*.cs (ViewModel)

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyCollection.Add("Item " + i);
        }
        MySelectedItem = "Item 2";
    }


    private ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return myCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            myCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        }
    }


    private string _mySelectedItem;
    public string MySelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _mySelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _mySelectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
        }
    }

    //NotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```